# Angular: How to add a class to a nested element of a child component

Tags: css, angular

I have a component that is an input + a dropdown list `DropdownSelect`, how can I add a class to an element nested in the dropdown list component?

**Input + Dropdown HTML**

```
<input class="number-input"
       #input
       [(ngModel)]="value.input"
       (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)"
       (blur)="onInputBlur()">
<app-dropdown-select [dropdownItems]="dropdownItems"
                     [(selectedItem)]="value.dropdownItem"
                     (selectedItemChange)="onDropdownChange($event)"
                     combinedInput="true"
                     class="dropdown-btn">
</app-dropdown-select>
```

**DropdownSelect component:**

```
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="dropdown-button"
       (click)="onClick($event)"
       [class.dropdown-active]="showList && !combinedInput"
       [class.dropdown-input-active]="showList && combinedInput">
    <div class="downdown-selected-item">
      {{selectedItem?.name}} {{selectedItem?.unit}}
    </div>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <i class="material-icons">
      {{buttonIcon}}
    </i>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-items" *ngIf="showList">
    <div *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems"
         (click)="onClickItem(item)"
         class="dropdown-item">
      {{item.name}},
      {{item.description}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add class `invalid` to the element with class `dropdown-button`

I've managed to add class to the component, don't know how to add to inner element.

```
@ViewChild(DropdownSelectComponent, { read: ElementRef }) dropdownSelectComponent: ElementRef;
```

**add class:**

```
this.dropdownSelectComponent.nativeElement.classList.add('invalid');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you could achieve this and I'll explain one below.

If you want to conditionally apply the invalid class from the outer component one way you can do it is to add an additional `@Input()` variable, in the compnents.ts file, to pass into your component so it would look like:

```
<input class="number-input"
       #input
       [(ngModel)]="value.input"
       (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)"
       (blur)="onInputBlur()">
<app-dropdown-select [dropdownItems]="dropdownItems"
                     [(selectedItem)]="value.dropdownItem"
                     (selectedItemChange)="onDropdownChange($event)"
                     combinedInput="true"
                     [invalidInput]="{{condition}}"
                     class="dropdown-btn">
</app-dropdown-select>
```

Then within the component itself you could add an `[ngClass]` binding so the inner component would end up looking like this:

```
...
<div class="dropdown-button"
       (click)="onClick($event)"
       [class.dropdown-active]="showList && !combinedInput"
       [class.dropdown-input-active]="showList && combinedInput"
       [ngClass]="{'invalid': invalidInput}">
    <div class="downdown-selected-item">
      {{selectedItem?.name}} {{selectedItem?.unit}}
    </div>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <i class="material-icons">
      {{buttonIcon}}
    </i>
...
```

More on the ngClass angular binding can be found here https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass